# Data manipulation for igraph

Tags: r

My goal is to transform rows by group into combination in order to use igraph.

Example i want to go from this:

```
start  <- data.frame(id = c(2,3,5,6),
            group_a = c("A","A","b","b"))
```

to this:

```
end <- data.frame(src = c(2,5),dst=c(3,6))
```

A little bit of explanation , since "A" has 2 and 3 then 2 is connected to 3 , "b" has 5 and 6 then 5 is connected to 6

I tried doing a inner join but i end up with all interactions:

```
sqldf("select a.id as src ,
              b.id as dst
      from start a   
      inner join start b on a.group_a = b.group_a")
```

I also check some documentation on igraph to see if there is a function that does it directly but i don't seem to find something that works. I tried this:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(start)
get.edgelist(g)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using dplyr

```
start %>% group_by(group_a) %>% do(data.frame(t(combn(.$id, 2))))
```